# LOAD DATA INFILE returns 0 rows affected, MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

It has been here already, but I did not find the answer.
I am trying to insert data from a csv file into mysql table customers using LOAD DATA INFILE command

I have used many modification of this syntax, but it always returns 0 rows affected. Where do I make mistake? This is my syntax (running MySQL 8 Server on Windows Server 2017 enviroment)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/customers.csv' INTO TABLE customers
CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES (ID,ClientNo,CustomerNo,LastName,FirstName,PhoneNumber,FaxNumber,PhoneNumberPrivate,MobileNumber,Email);
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
ID,ClientNo,CustomerNo,LastName,FirstName,PhoneNumber,FaxNumber,PhoneNumberPrivate,MobileNumber,Email
4911556,19,540789,Name1,Name2,00403651205,,,+403651205,luboxxxx5@axxxt.com
4911560,19,540790,Name52,Name56,015344492,,,+15344492,alxx.ss@gmail.com
4911561,19,540791,Name222,Name58,0904385448,,,4385448,
4911562,19,540792,Name547,Name555,7314727,,,+07314727,
4911967,5,1311473,Name789,Name562,+444839,,,,semxxxx@cxxxxrum.com
```

The table I want to insert looks like this:
`CREATE TABLE 'customers' (
  'ID' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   'ClientNo' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  'CustomerNo' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  'FirstName' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'LastName' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'PhoneNumber' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'FaxNumber' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'PhoneNumberPrivate' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'MobileNumber' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Email' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

I really do not know now, where and what. It will be some detail what I missed I suppose, but I am not able to see it now. Could someone shortly look please?

Comment: any errors other than "0 rows affected" ?

Comment: nope :/
0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: try by removing the following line CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4

Comment: just did.. same result ..

Comment: okay .. try "  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' " instead of "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' "... if it is still not working  try "  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' " instead of " LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' "

Comment: I tried already yesterday... I get this error (same for '\n' or '\r')
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ID' at row 1

Comment: are you sure you added " IGNORE 1 LINES " while executing '\n' or '\r', because the error  " Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ID' at row 1 " may occur due to the insertion of csv without skipping field name

Comment: yes, I am sure. If I exclude "ingore 1 lines" the error code appears:
Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string: ''

Comment: maybe, this could be the clue.... the character '' what cannot be represented as integer... means, that I have to exclude this... but if I open the csv in Notepad++, I cannot see anything like ''

Comment: how do I exclude this empty character? '' in the syntax?

Comment: maybe you can create a new table like your original table by using " create table newtable like oldtable; " and change the datatype of "ID" field to varchar and then insert your csv. After successful insertion change the datatype of " ID " field to int (if any error occurs while changing varchar to int , find it and correct it, you can easily find the errors by querying your new table) and then take a csv from your new table and load it to your original table

Comment: I have created a new table, as a copy of the current one. All datatypes in this new table are set to "varchar". If I use '\r\n' I get the same result - 0 rows affected, 0 errors and 0 warnings. If I use only '\r' or '\n', the result is the same, which is: Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'Email' at row 33

Comment: okay then your first issue is solved, this is a new issue... check email in row 33 in your csv .. it will be either greater than 50 characters or there will be some special characters which is causing the error.. if it is greater than 50 characters you need to increase varchar value

Comment: I am affraid, that this is not the issue. There is no such email with lenght more than 50 characters. At rows between 30 and 35, there are emails, in my csv file, with maximum lenght 25 characters. I really do not know, what this is. I suspect, that it tries to input characters in one row. I am confused about this.

Comment: loading a csv is really a headache.. if you are familiar with workbench you can try to load that csv using workbench

Comment: I know.. but I need to run it through script, beacuase it needs to be planned every day... So I need plan this task as a job. :/

Comment: I have changed the csv column delimiter from CR+LF to ";".. then I modified the script with the syntax LINES TERMINATED BY ';' ... now it throws an error Data too long for column 'Email' at row 10 ... going to investigate

Comment: .....confused... row 10, column 'Email' has less than 50 characters and there only characters like '@' or '.' .. nothing more... :/

Comment: we missed something in that csv.. don't know what

Comment: I can generate that CSV as I want.. whit delimiters I want... I tried to used different characters as delimiters... I have all the time same result. Could it be something else? the CSV has like 1,7 millions rows

Comment: no idea.. there is something wrong with that csv,  either it has some special characters which causing the error or something else

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that the column names in the first row were quoted and the data was imported with `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'` (and `ESCAPED BY '"'`). Actually, I found that any single quote would lead to the "0 rows affected" result.

Not exactly as described in the question but probably related.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` to `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same issue. I think it has something to do with numbers that start with 0. My column (zipcode) was indeed set to VARCHAR but to no use.

But importing only worked after I opened the CSV in excel which automatically got rid of 0s at the beginning of the number. So now, instead of ["01234"], [1234] showed in the CSV (opened in notepad, used [ ] just to indicate where the value starts and ends).

Luckily for me, I could easily `CONCAT("0", zipcode) WHERE zipcode<100000` to restore the true data.

So I suggest maybe finding a way to get rid of the 0 at the beginning or replacing it with a character and adding the 0 afterwards? That's all I got ¯_(ツ)_/¯ (doesn't work, read edit)

Edit: I tried replacing the 0 in front with a $ (did it in excel) and got rid of the " in the CSV file, but it still did not work, 0 rows affected. I'm super confused. I also tried removing special characters like "ã" but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

load data infile 'path'
into table online_retail
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '/n'
ignore 1 rows

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it